# exit status 1 expected primary-expression before '.' token

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm trying to get the temperature and humidity every 60 seconds, but my code won't work. Whenever I compile it, there's this error "expected primary-expression before '.' token"

This line gets highlighted.

`Serial.print(DHT.humidity,0);//prints humidity in serial`

Here's my entire code:

```
#include <DHT_U.h>
#define DHT12PIN 7// sets pin 7 for DHT11 signal connection

void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);//opens serial  
}

void loop()
{
  int chk = DHT.read12(DHT12PIN);//reads DHT12

  Serial.print(DHT.temperature,0);//prints temp in serial
  Serial.print(",");//pints comma in serial
  Serial.print(DHT.humidity,0);//prints humidity in serial  
  Serial.println(); //carraiage return  
  delay(2000);//wait 2 seconsds
}
```

Comment: does only humidity have problem?

Comment: i don't know, but it's the only line that gets highlighted

Comment: check it by commenting humidity, this //Serial.print(DHT.humidity,0);

Comment: Add () on end so it will look like

Serial.print(DHT.temperature(),0);
Serial.print(DHT.humidity(),0);

Tell me if you have any other problem.

Comment: How do you compile you code?

Comment: @samini apparently temperature does have a problem too

Comment: @dzuda11 it still has the same error

Comment: @NellieDanielyan i verifiy it using the verifiy button at the top left

Comment: Ok, did you downloaded and include the library? Do you have DTH folder in Arduino/library?

Comment: Try adding dht DHT; after including the header

Comment: Read your DHT_U library. I doubt `.humidity` is a public numeric property. ( Maybe there's a method `humidity()`  )

Comment: OT your question states: *I'm trying to get the temperature and humidity every 60 seconds*  but the code contains: `delay(2000);//wait 2 seconsds`  Which is only 2 seconds, not 60

Answer (score 2):

Wow there was a lot to unpack in this question.

I have used the [DHT library](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library) by Adafruit a lot of times and thought that you just ended up using the class name instead of instantiating a variable and that's why you were facing the issue.

But then I realized that you are using the following function which is not a part of the Adafruit library:

```
int chk = dht.read12(DHT12PIN);//reads DHT12
```

So, I did a bit of digging on the internet and realized that someone has made a library for DHT with that specific function. [(A lot of libraries to be specific)](https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino)

Based on my analysis of this library, and the [example](https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/DHTstable/examples/dht12_test/dht12_test.ino) code that was given, you have 3 issues.

1. You have included the wrong header file. The header file `dht.h` from  [RobTillaart's library](https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino) should replace the header file `DHT_U.h` of [Adafruit's library](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library), in your code.
2. You have to instantiate the variable named `DHT` of the `dht` class. This can be done as follows, above your setup function

   `dht DHT;`
3. Given that you had the code and the header files mixed up from TWO DIFFERENT LIBRARIES, I am guessing that you have installed the [Adafruit library](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library), in the place of [RobTillaart's library](https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino). To fix this, you will have to remove the `DHT-sensor-library-1.3.4` from your `Documents/Arduino/libraries`, create a new folder named `DHTStable` in it's place, and place all of the files listed [here](https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/DHTstable/) in the new folder.

Some words of experience-based wisdom, don't use [RobTillaart's library](https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino), I can tell from a glance of it's folder structure that you will face more problems then you can solve if you use it. Instead use [Adafruit's library](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library), with their [example](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHT_Unified_Sensor/DHT_Unified_Sensor.ino). You will also have to install [Adafruit's sensor library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Sensor), but it is definitely worth it.